# Get attribute of clicked link with JS function

Tags: javascript, attributes, hyperlink

there is html structure:

```
<a onclick="setString()">
  <img alt="no" />
</a>
```

I need to get attribute of `a`,that had been clicked,e.g. `alt`.

How to know with setString() js function , 
  image with what `alt` attribute is clicked?

I assume,that somehow with `this`,but don't know how.

Comment: What does the clientside code look like after it is rendered? Looking at serverside code is useless.

Comment: @Felix Kling  it's 'a' HTML element,post is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change my HTML to remove the bits that aren't needed...

```
<img alt="no" onclick="setString(this.alt);" />
```

Rather than wrapping the image in an anchor tag, style it with CSS if you want...

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="setString(this)
```

///Javascript Code:

```
function setString(element){

var value = element.children[0].alt;

}
```

Comment: element.childNodes is undefined

Comment: element is treated as [object Window],looks like need more deeper traverse

Comment: @sergio: Use `element.children`. `childNodes` also returns text nodes. See http://jsfiddle.net/ZeDxN/ And don't forget to pass `this` in the call to `setString`.

Comment: you need to add (this) as a parameter in the <a> element

Comment: also, just updated the answer, its [1] instead of [0] sorry about that.

Comment: @Rikal: Better is to use `children` here. You never know how many (empty) text nodes there are in the DOM.

Comment: @Felix, that is a good point. Changed the code to reflect this.

Comment: @Felix Kling strange, it warns,that children is undefined in my app,but it works  in your example OK, perhaps JSF issue,because i have action attr for this link also