# How to get the ID from an option value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to know how to save the `$row['id']` selected by the user to a variable ready to be stored to my db.

can i solve whit something like this?

```html
<form action="shippingmethod.php" method="post" role="form" class="send-it-test">
  <select class="form-control search-slt" name="selezione_sede">
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT id,city,address FROM sedi ORDER BY city";
      $ris = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ris)){
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id']."'>" . $row['city'] ." ,". $row['address']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you make a `select` with a `name` attribute and put it in a `form`?

Comment: yes i have made a select with an id

Comment: First of all what @user3783243 says is true and another is you will need js for this puropse.And if you have js code please share it too.

Comment: `id`s aren't accessible to PHP. How are you sending the value?

Comment: i'm sending it through POST method, but i would like to pass only the $row['id'] value.

Comment: Are you using JS or a `<form>`? The question is too minimal please update to show how you currently are submitting the data, what it is submitting, and what it should be submitting.

Comment: i 'm using a form at the moment and another php file to handle the data.
But i cannot extract the value from the <option>

Comment: So you can get the value by js and post it to another page via ajax your job will be done.

Comment: can you suggest me a little script for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get attribute of clicked link with JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126923/get-attribute-of-clicked-link-with-js-function)

Comment: @KunalRaut i have added an ajax script now but can you tell me how to handle the central part (the commented one)? how can i select only my id?

Comment: Ok give me a sec i'll give you whole working code.

Comment: Your example should already work, that is, achieve the value of the selected option that corresponds to `$row['id']`. Sending the form to the `shippingmethod.php` file accesses the value using for example `$selezione_sede = $ _POST ['selezione_sede'];` so `$ selezione_sede` stores the value of `$row['id']` then you can implement the next task

Comment: @unraken you want to do it with `ajax`?

Comment: No @KUMAR, the method suggest by KunalRaut works fine for my project.

Comment: @unraken why you edited your code again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your just want to save your value to database you can just make use of global variable `$_POST` as

In the same php file.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" role="form" class="send-it-test">
  <select class="form-control search-slt" name="selezione_sede">
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT id,city,address FROM sedi ORDER BY city";
      $ris = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ris)){
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id']."'>" . $row['city'] ." ,". $row['address']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$value = $_POST['selezione_sede'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help you @unraken :)